# Enviar valores de un select mysql a varios inputs en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un selectbox poblado desde mysql desde una tabla con dos campos (id y nombre). El selectbox muestra la lista de nombres. Necesito que al seleccionar un elemento del select envíe el id a un input text y el nombre a otro input text.
Por ahora, he logrado pasar con javascript el valor nombre a un imput text, pero no logro pasar el id  al otro input text.

Éste es el código que tengo.

```
<html>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $('#myInput').val(value);
                $('#myInput2').val(value);
            });
        });
      </script>
   </head>
</html>

<?php
    require('conexion.php');
    if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $conn->error);
    }

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * from business");

    //config form
    echo '<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="generarqr.php" method="post">';
    echo '<select id="mySelect">';
    echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione la empresa</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['Nombre'] . '">' . $row['Nombre'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input id="myInput"  name="data"/>';

    echo '<select id="mySelect2">';
    echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione la empresa</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['Nombre'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input id="myInput2"  name="ids"/>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="GENERATE"></form>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo lo que quieres es selecionar el valor mas el texto, si es asi te falta utilizar el `text()` para obtener el literal de la seleccion y en cuanto al valor o id ya lo haces con `val()`.

Te dejo un ejemplo, para que lo pruebes y adaptes a lo que nesecitas:

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function () {
        var tagOption = $('option:selected', this);
        $('#myInput').val(tagOption.val());
        $('#myInput2').val(tagOption.text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="v1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="v2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="v3">Valor 3</option>
  <option value="v4">Valor 4</option>
</select>

<br><br>
Valor: <input type="text" id="myInput" />

<br><br>
Texto: <input type="text" id="myInput2" />


</body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas primero se guarda una referencia a la opcion seleccionada con:
`$('option:selected', this);` de esta forma forzamos a seleccionar siempre el valor correcto y no tener problemas al hacer `text()`.